# How to extract emojis using HiveQL?

Tags: utf-8, hiveql

I'd like to compute the frequency of each single emoji in a Hive table. To do that, I'm trying to extract single emojis, or split a sentence into words / emojis properly using HiveQL.

For example, I have `'hotel ❤️ *'` as UTF-8 format in my Hive table, and I want to get the following as results:
`'hotel', '','❤️', '*'`

My progress so far:

1. if I use the following code, I could separate data by blanks but not splitting the two emojis

result: 
`'hotel', '❤️', '*'`

code:

```
select split(col_name,'[ ]')
FROM the_table;
```

2. I know I could use something like `regexp_extract` to extract desired emojis, but I don't have a comprehensive list of emojis, so still can't leverage that to get what I want.

```
SELECT regexp_extract('hotel ❤️ *', '[⚾️]', 0);
```